# Unset an associative array on foreach loop if this key is found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array of data, all I wanted is to check if this key is found, cause if it is I will unset a certain array

This would be my example array:

```
Array
(
  [2019-01-01] => Array(
     [1] => Array(
        ['OLD'] => Array(
          [0] => Array(
            ['id']=>1,
            ['name']=>full name
          )
        )
        ['NEW'] => Array(
          [0] => Array(
            ['id']=>2,
            ['name']=>full name
          )
        )
     )
  )
  [2019-01-02] => Array(
     [1] => Array(
        ['OLD'] => Array(
          [0] => Array(
            ['id']=>5,
            ['name']=>full name
          )
        )
     )
  )
)
```

I have this code:

```
foreach ($my_array as $key=>$val) {
  foreach ($val as $key=>$val) {
    foreach ($val as $key=>$val) {
      // I wanted to check in this part if this array has `$key` OLD and `$key` NEW, if it has new then unset OLD
    }
  }
}
```

My expected result would be the OLD to be removed if there is NEW, but If there is no NEW then retain OLD array. What is the proper `array` function to use here?

Comment: I don't feel like I have enough details to offer a confident solution.  Please give your desired output from the input. Are you comparing indexes within a given day? Are we matching `id` values? Your sample input is rather basic.  How might it vary? I don't recommend reusing the same variable name in successive loops.

Comment: Might you have more than one subarray in a given date-keyed subarray? Your sample only shows `[1]`s.  If n9t, you should remove that level from your data structure to make your code simpler.  Same advice for `[0]` keyed level.

Comment: This is one foreach loop too many. Instead of the inner loop, you should check for the existence of the 'NEW' key inside the second-level foreach loop. (And overwriting the loop variables by naming them the same in all loops would of course not be a clever thing to do, if that is your actual code.)

Answer (score 2):

Simply [**array_walk()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) might help you. Example:

```
array_walk($arr, function (&$item) {
    if(isset($item[1]['OLD'], $item[1]['NEW'])) unset($item[1]['OLD']);
});
```